# I have List of file names and have datatable contain keywords , How can check for files which don't have any one of keywords?

Tags: c#

I have list of files and `DataTable` contains keywords. I want to get list of files which don't contain any one of keywords?

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in keywords.Rows)
    {
        if (!files.Any(f => f.Contains(row.ItemArray[0].ToString())))
        //if (!files.Any(f => f.Contains(keywords.Rows[i])))
        {
            FilesMissing.Add(file);

            List<string> FileNotCorrect = (from d in FilesMissing select d).Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **1)** What type is your `files` variable? **2)** The outer `foreach` seems to be obsolete - you perform `files.Any()` in the inner loop. **3)** What's the puprpose of `FileNotCorrect`. **4)** Don't mix [query syntax and method syntax in LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq).

Comment: Use not : .!Contains(row.ItemArray[0].ToString()

Comment: declare the `row.ItemArray[0].ToString()` first.